# Want to match the pattern in php

Tags: php, regex

I want to match pattern for the below string:
**(String is dynamic means i am getting it in request from html form, so it may be new every time but format of string will always same)**

**Actually i want that keywords(name,salary,account) that may be different in every request**

```
$str="$(name) is $(salary) and $(account)";
if(preg_match_all("/\$\((.+?)\)/is",$str,$arrmsgvar,PREG_SET_ORDER)){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arrmsgvar);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

I am writing regex to match that pattern but not getting successful. would anyone please tell   me the  right regex for above code?

Comment: @Campfire [lazy operators](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Comment: Can you show a test with the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression (and search string too if you want to be sure) should be in single quotes.

With double quotes, PHP interprets your regular expression as this:

```
/$\((.+?)\)/
 ^
missing backslash here
```

This code should work just fine.

```
<?php

$str='$(name) is $(salary) and $(account)';
if(preg_match_all('/\$\((.+?)\)/',$str,$arrmsgvar,PREG_SET_ORDER)){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arrmsgvar);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

[**Proof**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7wooiK)

Answer (score 0):

This regex will return an array with the three values

```
"/\$\((\w+)\)/"

preg_match_all("/\$\((\w+)\)/",$str,$arrmsgvar);

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => $(name)
        [1] => $(salary)
        [2] => $(account)
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => name
        [1] => salary
        [2] => account
    )

)
```